# Complicated Calculation within SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-xe, ora-00932

I posted a similar question yesterday with the same code, I have rewritten and it should be perfect to a new specification but for some reason it is not working.

I am using Oracle 10g Express.

The code below is working out the top 10% of earning solicitors.

```
CREATE VIEW rich_solicitors AS
select notes.time_spent*rate.rate_amnt+coalesce(special_rate.s_rate_amnt,0)
AS solicitor_made, notes.solicitor_id
FROM notes, rate, solicitor_rate, solicitor, case, contract, special_rate
WHERE notes.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
AND solicitor.solicitor_id = solicitor_rate.solicitor_id
AND solicitor_rate.rate_id = rate.rate_id
AND notes.case_id = case.case_id
AND case.contract_id = contract.contract_id
AND contract.contract_id = special_rate.contract_id (+)
ORDER BY -solicitor_made;


SELECT * FROM rich_solicitors
WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*)/10 FROM rich_solicitors);
```

I need to work out the top 10% of last year, I thought it would be as easy as adding the start_date and expiry_date to the SELECT and adding the following WHERE function:

```
AND contract.start_date >= 01-01-10
AND contract.expiry_date <= 01-01-11
```

I have inserting the date corectly using TO_DATE. My lecturer spent a good hour with me working out why this wouldnt work but to no avail.

It kept on returning the error - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

I also tried defining the date format and that still returned the same error

```
CREATE VIEW rich_solicitors1 AS
SELECT  notes.time_spent*rate.rate_amnt+coalesce(special_rate.s_rate_amnt,0) AS solicitor_made, notes.solicitor_id, TO_CHAR(contract.start_date, 'DD-MM-YY'), TO_CHAR(contract.expiry_date, 'DD-MM-YY')
FROM notes, rate, solicitor_rate, solicitor, case, contract, special_rate
WHERE notes.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
AND solicitor.solicitor_id = solicitor_rate.solicitor_id
AND solicitor_rate.rate_id = rate.rate_id
AND notes.case_id = case.case_id
AND case.contract_id = contract.contract_id
AND contract.contract_id = special_rate.contract_id (+)
AND contract.start_date >= 01-01-10
AND contract.expiry_date <= 01-01-11
ORDER BY -solicitor_made;
```

any ideas?

Many thanks, any criticism is much appreciated, I am a student and at my very first steps with this, before about 9 days ago I had no SQL knowledge at all.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to format my code properly on here, is it a browser error? any advice?

Comment: @Phil: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: @NullUserException: Hey, you're back! It's been long :)

Comment: @NullUserException - thank you for formatting this properly

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you for the link, I shall get reading, as soon as this assignment is out of the way.

Comment: @Bolt Yeah, on a temporary basis :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try i have replaced your coalesce by NVL function

```
SELECT  notes.time_spent*rate.rate_amnt+NVL(special_rate.s_rate_amnt,0) 
AS solicitor_made, notes.solicitor_id, TO_CHAR(contract.start_date, 'DD-MM-YY'), 
TO_CHAR(contract.expiry_date, 'DD-MM-YY') 
FROM notes, rate, solicitor_rate, solicitor, case, contract, special_rate 
WHERE notes.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id 
AND solicitor.solicitor_id = solicitor_rate.solicitor_id 
AND solicitor_rate.rate_id = rate.rate_id AND notes.case_id = case.case_id 
AND case.contract_id = contract.contract_id 
AND contract.contract_id = special_rate.contract_id (+) 
AND contract.start_date >= to_date('01-01-10','MM-DD-YY')
AND contract.expiry_date <= to_date('01-01-11' ,'MM-DD-YY')
ORDER BY solicitor_made
```

Comment: Drat! You beat me to it! Darned phone rang. :-)

Comment: That was me on the phone trying to talk to you so i can collect a point or two here ;-)

Comment: Can you do a desc contract just want to check up on the datatypes

Comment: sorry, not sure what a desc contract is? do you mean you want to see my create table for contract?

Comment: Yes if you have sqlplus you can simply do desc contract which will display the table with its datatypes

Comment: CREATE TABLE contract ( contract_id VARCHAR(7), client_id VARCHAR   (7), start_date DATE, expiry_date DATE, PRIMARY KEY (    contract_id ), FOREIGN KEY ( client_id ) REFERENCES client(client_id) );

Comment: I am sorry, I have got to get to grips with inserting code in this forum - only my second post mind, @BoltClock thanks for the link on code formatting will read through now!

Comment: When I inserted the dates i used this method for my insert scripts        INSERT INTO contract (contract_id,client_id,start_date,expiry_date) VALUES ( 'R5Z 8G2','P4G 3M1',to_date('15/09/10','DD/MM/YY'),to_date('15/09/13','DD/MM/YY'));

Comment: Sorry late reply, it is still returning same error, all of the data types are defianltely correct, could it be something to do with the fact that it is multiplying time spent a rate of a solicitor first?

Comment: before i added the to_date and char-date, I was recieving the error expected DATE got NUMBER... s=

Comment: That is incredible.. Thank you, it is soo close - when I run that I get no rows selected, however when I remove the AND expiry_date statement I get all cases that started after 01-Jan-2010 - Why do you think that it would not select any rows when the expiry AND statement is included? the dates are correct /=

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOO Im an idiot, (and my lecturer come to think of it) the start date needs to between 01-JAN-2010 and 01-JAN-2011 - the expiry date has literally NOTHING to do with it!!! Thank you soo soo much, I would give you many kissses if you werent on a different continent - probably for the better though hey? Thank you - I look forward to the day that I may be able to help some one on here!

Comment: This answer would be SO much better if you just specified century information in the date as well. So, instead of to_date('01-01-11' ,'MM-DD-YY'), you should write to_date('01-01-2011' ,'MM-DD-YYYY') or simply date '2011-01-01'.

Answer (score 2):

Phil, your query using ROWNUM will *not* get the top 10% by any definition of "top" that I can think of.

An example that will is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT solicitor_made, solicitor_id
        ,NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY solicitor_made DESC) decile
  FROM rich_solicitors
) WHERE decile = 1;
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed you have an ORDER BY in your view definition. In which case your ROWNUM method will work. Normally I recommend against putting ORDER BY in a view definition.

Comment: I am only getting to the top by ordering so that the highest earners are first and only displaying the first % of rows, but this is obviuosly by far more accurate.... well its right which is different.. thank you.